# Syntax error in Rails server with wash_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, soap

I'm trying to build a SOAP service with Ruby on Rails 3. After a lot of research I found `Wash_out`.

Now, when I add the gem to my gemfile, like this:

```
gem 'wash_out'
```

My rails application no longer starts, I mean, when I type 'rails s' it gives me an error with wash_out.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wash_out-0.6.1/lib/wash_out.rb:3:in `require':     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wash_out-0.6.1/lib/wash_out/dispatcher.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected '\n' (SyntaxError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wash_out-0.6.1/lib/wash_out.rb:3
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/TheBcd/Escritorio/ws/config/application.rb:7
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

I'd appreciate any help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your trace log I'm assuming you're using ruby 1.8 and a short reading of the gem's github shows this:

> Rails >3.0 only. MRI 1.9, 2.0, JRuby (--1.9).
>
> Ruby 1.8 is not officially supported since 0.5.3. We will accept
>   further compatibilty pull-requests but no upcoming versions will be
>   tested against it.

So, if you want to use the gem with 1.8 support it'd be wise to lock the version to anything under `0.5.3`. Try setting your gem version in your Gemfile to something under that version and it will probably work but like they say, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Hi Leo. You're right I just notice that I'm using Ruby 1.8. However I'd set your answer as the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`wash_out` [requires Ruby 1.9](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out#compatibility). Your backtrace shows Ruby 1.8.